# How to eliminate ability bias?

Tags: econometrics

Suppose I have an equation: $$\ln(wage_i)= \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot Education_i + \alpha_i + \varepsilon_i$$

an adjustment for the measurement error shows that an added year of education increases wages by 18%.

How would I mathematically eliminate ability bias?

Answer (score 2):

You can't fully eliminate ability bias, but you could certainly take steps to reduce it.  One obvious way is to add additional "ability" variables to your model to control or statistically adjust for the ability bias.  For example, people with IQ tend to obtain better paying jobs with or without additional education.  So, you if you can measure IQ, include it as a control ($\alpha_{2i}$) in your regression model.

Also "A common remedy adopted in the literature is to estimate the relationship between wage and education level by instrumenting schooling outcomes with variables that are orthogonal to ability."  See Angrist and Krueger (1991), Angrist (1990), Card (1995), Harmon and Walker (1995)) for additional details.